# A dynamic memory resource with alignment support

Tags: c, memory-management, c11

Although C11 introduced `aligned_alloc( alignment, size )`, there is no support for aligned reallocation (AFAIK). The `memory_resource` structure that follows and its related functions provide such functionality.

I wanted to provide something with as little overhead as possible, which is why there's close to no error checking done. I envisioned this structure being wrapped in another structure that does do safety checks if that is required. Is this reasonable design?

`memory_resource` features:

- Support for over-aligned dynamic allocation.
- Can be resized.
- Can be realigned.

`memory_resource_xxx` function family pre-conditions:

- Pointer to `struct memory_resource` arguments shall not be `NULL` or modified outside of these functions.
- Alignment arguments shall be powers of 2.

Note: My library does not have `aligned_alloc( alignment, size )`.

Sample usage:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <assert.h>

int main()
{
    struct memory_resource mr;
    size_t align = 32;
    size_t size = 4000;

    if ( memory_resource_initialize( &mr, align, size ) )
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to allocate memory." );

    assert( (uintptr_t)mr.aligned_ptr % align == 0 );
    assert( mr.size == size );

    if ( memory_resource_resize( &mr, size * 2 ) )
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to allocate memory." );

    assert( (uintptr_t)mr.aligned_ptr % align == 0 );
    assert( mr.size == size * 2 );

    align = 64;
    if ( memory_resource_realign( &mr, align ) )
        fprintf( stderr, "unable to allocate memory." );

    assert( (uintptr_t)mr.aligned_ptr % align == 0 );

    if ( memory_resource_resize( &mr, 1024 ) )
        fprintf( stderr, "strange" );

    assert( (uintptr_t)mr.size == 1024 );
    assert( (uintptr_t)mr.aligned_ptr % align == 0 );
    memory_resource_free( &mr );
}
```

*memory_resource.h*

```
#ifndef MEMORY_RESOURCE_20160823_H
#define MEMORY_RESOURCE_20160823_H

#include <stddef.h>

/**
 * @struct an aligned, dynamically allocated memory resource
 */
struct memory_resource
{
    void* block;
    void* aligned_ptr;
    size_t align;
    size_t size;
    size_t extra_block_size;
};

/**
 * @brief initializes the specified memory resource to the specified alignment and size
 * @param dst: pointer to the memory resource to be initialized
 * @param align: alignment boundary of the memory resource
 * @param size: size, in bytes, of the memory resource
 * @return 0 if the memory resource was allocated successfully, 1 otherwise.
 */
int memory_resource_initialize( struct memory_resource* dst,
    size_t const align, size_t const size );

/**
 * @brief frees the specified memory resource
 * @param dst: pointer to the memory resource to be freed
 */
void memory_resource_free( struct memory_resource* dst );

/**
 * @brief resizes a memory resource
 * @param dst: pointer to the memory resource to be resized
 * @param size: new size of the memory resource
 * @return 0 if the memory resource was resized, 1 otherwise
 */
int memory_resource_resize( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const size );

/**
 * @brief realigns a memory resource; might require reallocation in order
          to maintain proper alignment when align > ( *dst ).align
 * @param dst: pointer to the memory resource to be realigned
 * @param align: new alignment boundary of the memory resource
 * @return 0 if the memory resource was realigned, 1 if the memory resource
 *         is unable to allocate enough space to be properly aligned
 */
int memory_resource_realign( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const align );

#endif // MEMORY_RESOURCE_20160823_H
```

*memory_resource.c*

```
#include "memory_resource.h"
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdint.h>

// source: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9194117/2296177
#define make_aligned( block, align )\
(void*)( ( (uintptr_t)block + align - 1 ) & ~( align - 1 ) )

typedef struct
{
    void* aligned_ptr;
    size_t padding;
} align_calc_t;

static align_calc_t alignment_calculation( void* block, size_t const align )
{
    align_calc_t result;
    result.aligned_ptr = make_aligned( block, align );
    result.padding = (uintptr_t)result.aligned_ptr - (uintptr_t)block;
    return result;
}

int memory_resource_initialize( struct memory_resource* dst,
    size_t const align, size_t const size )
{
    void* block = malloc( align + size );
    if ( block )
    {
        dst->block = block;
        dst->aligned_ptr = make_aligned( block, align );
        dst->align = align;
        dst->size = size;
        dst->extra_block_size = align;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

void memory_resource_free( struct memory_resource* dst )
{
    free( dst->block );
}

int memory_resource_resize( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const size )
{
    void* block = realloc( dst->block, size + dst->align );
    if ( block )
    {
        if ( block != dst->block )
        {
            dst->block = block;
            dst->aligned_ptr = make_aligned( block, dst->align );
        }
        dst->size = size;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int memory_resource_realign( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const align )
{
    if ( align < dst->align )
    {
        dst->align = align;
        return 0;
    }
    else if ( align > dst->align )
    {
        align_calc_t ac = alignment_calculation( dst->block, align );
        if ( ac.padding > dst->extra_block_size )
        {
            void* block = realloc( dst->block, align + dst->size );
            if ( block )
            {
                dst->block = block;
                dst->aligned_ptr = make_aligned( block, align );
                dst->align = align;
                dst->extra_block_size = align;
                return 0;
            }
            return 1;
        }
        else
        {
            dst->aligned_ptr = ac.aligned_ptr;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Bug**

  The padding between `block` and `aligned_ptr` depends on how well `block` was aligned. There is no guarantee that the padding after original `malloc` is the same as the padding after `realloc`, so `memory_resource_resize` may copy the client data to a misaligned location, and therefore the `aligned_ptr` will not point the start of client data.
- **Realignment**

  Consider the scenario:

  ```
  memory_resource_initialize(&mr, 32, ...);
  memory_resource_realign(&mr, 4);
  memory_resource_realign(&mr, 8);
  ```

  Since the first realignment is a no-op, the resource is still happily aligned on a 32-byte boundary. The second realignment doesn't need to do anything, but reallocation will still occur.
- **Interface**

  - `make_aligned` assumes that `align` is a power of 2, which imposes an extra burden to the client. I recommend you change it to *exponent*, that is `align` 5 shall requests a 32-byte boundary.
  - I don't think it is a good idea to expose a `memory_resource` type to the client at all. I recommend you reuse the "wasted" space for bookkeeping. Consider:

    ```
    void * aligned_malloc(size_t const size, size_t const align)
    {
        void * memory = malloc(size + align);
        void * data = make_aligned(memory, align);
        if (memory == data) {
            data = ((char *) memory) + align;
        }

        // Now you have enough bytes in front of data to accommodate the
        // larges scalar, and it is aligned nicely. Store the
        // metadata here.

        size_t * prefix = (size_t *) (((char *) data - sizeof(size));
        * prefix = (char *) data - (char *) memory;
        return data;
    }
    ```

  Now given the pointer returned by `aligned_malloc`, other functions (e.g. `aligned_realloc` and `aligned_free`) may easily recover the `memory` pointer, and safely `free` or `realloc` it.
- **Portability**

  The Standard guarantees that if you convert a void pointer to `uintptr_t`, and convert it back to void pointer, the result will compare equal to the original. Unfortunately, nothing else is guaranteed. It is not defined what `uintptr_t` is converted to once it has undergone arithmetic operations.

Comment: I'm not sure I quite understand what you mean by "re-use the wasted space", since that is not constant. It depends on required alignment and the integral value of the pointer returned by `malloc()`.

Comment: The resource was not meant to deal with `memcpy()` like behavior which is why it's missing where it would be needed. The issue you've brought up about realigning is very important, thank you.

Comment: 1) `size_t * prefix = (size_t *) (((char *) data - sizeof(size));` relies on `sizeof(size) >= align` which may not be true.  2) Pedantic: `size + align` may overflow.

Answer (score 1):

### On design

The original intent was unclear:

1. A memory resource *does not* worry itself about data that might exist in its buffer; it is up to the user to ensure proper data copying behaviour.
2. Due to the previous point, a memory resource *will* cause memory leaks on resize and realignment. Since it can't know whether data is in its buffer, it cannot free the data.
3. A new simple structure that manages a memory resource is ideal (I might say required), but I've not provided it in this post.

Due to **2.**, this is what proper use looks like:

```
void memcpy_resize_example( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const size )
{
    void* old_block = dst->block;
    void* old_aligned_ptr = dst->aligned_ptr;
    size_t const old_size = dst->size;
    if ( memory_resource_resize( dst, size ) )
    {
        /* error handling */
    }
    memcpy( dst->aligned_ptr, old_aligned_ptr, old_size );
    free( old_block );
}
```

Similar steps must be taken for realignment, which is why I classify **3.** as required.

### Taking advantage of `max_align_t`

From http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/types/max_align_t:

> Pointers returned by allocation functions such as malloc are suitably
>   aligned for any object, which means they are aligned at least as
>   strict as max_align_t.

For an alignment `a`, there's no need to allocate extra memory if `a <= alignof(max_align_t)`. All functions except for `memory_resource_free( dst )` must be modified.

Key points:

- All usage of `realloc( block, size )` has been removed. It should now be clear that no `memcpy( dst, src, size )` ever takes place. It is clear that copying falls on the user, as `struct memory_resource` cannot know whether its buffer contains actual data or not.
- It makes no sense to ever align below `alignof( max_align_t )`.
- Extra space is only required for alignments greater than `alignof( max_align_t )`.
- I posted this question too early/without the necessary self-examination.

The following is added to `memory_resource.c`:

```
#include <stdalign.h>
#define MALLOC_MIN_ALIGN alignof( max_align_t )
```

#### Modified `memory_resource_initialize( dst, align, size )`

Copying of members can be done a number of ways. I asked a question about this issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/39137029/2296177. I've chosen to simply write everything out.

```
int memory_resource_initialize( struct memory_resource* dst,
    size_t const align, size_t const size )
{
    if ( align > MALLOC_MIN_ALIGN )
    {
        void* block = malloc( align + size );
        if ( block )
        {
            dst->block = block;
            dst->aligned_ptr = make_aligned( block, align );
            dst->align = align;
            dst->extra_block_size = align;
            dst->size = size;
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        void* block = malloc( size );
        if ( block )
        {
            dst->block = block;
            dst->aligned_ptr = block;
            dst->align = MALLOC_MIN_ALIGN;
            dst->extra_block_size = 0;
            dst->size = size;
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

#### Modified `memory_resource_resize( dst, size )`

`dst->align > MALLOC_MIN_ALIGN` has already been computed by `memory_resource_initialize( dst, align, size )`. Adding another member to manage would add needless complexity and it would be a really bad case of premature optimization.

```
int memory_resource_resize( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const size )
{
    if ( dst->align > MALLOC_MIN_ALIGN )
    {
        void* new_block = malloc( size + dst->align );
        if ( new_block )
        {
            dst->block = new_block;
            dst->aligned_ptr = memcpy(
                make_aligned( new_block, dst->align ), dst->aligned_ptr, dst->size );
            dst->size = size;
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        void* new_block = malloc( size );
        if ( new_block )
        {
            dst->block = new_block;
            dst->aligned_ptr = memcpy( new_block, dst->aligned_ptr, dst->size );
            dst->size = size;
            return 0;
        }
        return 1;
    }
}
```

### Modified `memory_resource_realign( dst, align )`

This new scheme will not ever realign to an alignment that is less strict. This implies that there will be space wasted (not much) if some user reuses an over-aligned `struct memory_resource`. The previous use case should be rare; it might be prudent to provide some sort of `force_realign( dst, align )` function, however.

The following function is *not* a general purpose public API force realign; it is for use by the existing realign function (its declaration and definition is in `memory_resource.c`).

```
static int memory_resource_forced_realign( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const align )
{
    void* new_block = malloc( align + dst->size );
    if ( new_block )
    {
        dst->block = new_block;
        dst->aligned_ptr = make_aligned( new_block, align );
        dst->align = align;
        dst->extra_block_size = align;
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}
```

In addition, it makes more sense to return 0 (success) even if realignment turns out to be a no-op with this change (debatable?), so that users know (by testing the return) that the memory resource is aligned to their liking.

```
int memory_resource_realign( struct memory_resource* dst, size_t const align )
{
    if ( align > dst->align )
    {
        if ( dst->extra_block_size != 0 )
        {
            align_calc_t ac = alignment_calculation( dst->block, align );
            if ( ac.padding > dst->extra_block_size )
            {
                return memory_resource_forced_realign( dst, align );
            }
            else
            {
                dst->aligned_ptr = ac.aligned_ptr;
                dst->align = align;
                return 0;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return memory_resource_forced_realign( dst, align );
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```